# Web API2 Mocking EF and lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, lazy-loading, asp.net-web-api2

Hello and thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I am new to unit testing and have followed the article about "Mocking Entity Framework when Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2" [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2). Everything works fine with the exception of tests where lazy loading is required.

Some of the API controllers I am trying to unit test return a projection of the Entity into a DTO. Some properties of the DTO are populated thanks to lazy loading. For instance, I have an entity Child with the following definition:

```
public class Child {
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  //...other properties
  public Guid ParentId {get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The POST method in my childrenController returns a projection of the newly created Child Entity into a ChildViewModel DTO, where the definition of ChildViewModel is :

```
public class ChildViewModel
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  //...other properties
  public string ParentName{ get; set; }
  public ChildViewModel (Child obj)
  {
    Id = obj.Id;
    //...other properties
    ParentName = obj.Parent.Name;
  }
}
```

What confuses me is that everything works perfectly fine on the live system. The ParentName property is correctly populated. However, as soon as I run the unit test, the Parent property is null and therefore the test fails.

I have read extensively on unit testing and mocking EF but I have been unable find a solution to my problem. I would therefore appreciate some insight on what might be causing this behaviour. Is there any further mocking, beyond what is described in the article mentioned above, that I should implement to resolve this issue?

It is worth to note that:

1- The post method uses the method DBSet.Create() and not the new constructor to create the new entity to ensure that navigation properties are not null.

2- All others tests not involving lazy loading complete successfully.

3- The Parent entity exists in the test context before the Child Entity is created.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Looking at the source code you mention. Why on earth would you think that it would support Lazy Loading. Heck it doesn't even support Eager loading. As far as I am concerned this article is wrong and should not be followed. Consider using EF-SQL CE/localdb instead to create something that is Unit Test safe.

Comment: The reason this fails is because your `TestDbSet` does not support associations. You need to map those yourself during initialization. But `TestDbSet` completely bypasses Entity Framework. Its a BAD test substitute.

Comment: Thanks for your comments...However this confuses me even more...I am not trying to unit test EF, just my API Controllers...Using an SQL CE/localdb would fall into integration testing...Plus I do not believe that TestDbSet bypasses entirely EF, only the connection with the DB part, right ?

Comment: I am actually reading the source code. IT IS by passing EF. What I am suggesting if valid Unit Testing, if done correctly. Using SQL CE or LocalDB is what we call using a Testing Fake. You should be able to setup the scope of the test to create a new db file for each test. The point is that much of EF REQUIRES a database connection. Your API controller unfortunately requires lazy loading (a feature of EF), so you ARE integration testing.

Comment: Thanks Aron for pointing me in the right direction. The code from the article actually bypasses EF as you correctly indicated. To satisfy my requirement for testing the business logic inside the controllers, I ended up modifying the definition of TestDbSet and added a virtual method  `OnAdd(T item)` that gets called by the already existing `Add(T item)`. This allows me to map a dummy association when required and ensure that the DTO can be generated and the testing cycle completed. Moreover, the lazy loading in the DTO is the responsibility of EF and therefore I do not need to unit test it.